# Blocking DC when driving a buzzer with a PWM signal

Tags: dc, pwm, filter, piezo-buzzer

I am driving a piezo buzzer with a PWM signal (typical freq. 100Hz-1kHz) in order to generate 'beeps'. However due to software constrains (*), when the PWM signal is stopped I can't control if it stays at a high or a low level.

If it stays at a high level when stopped, then the power consumption of the buzzer increases, and it also generates more heat. I believe this could be solved if I could somehow block the DC component of the PWM signal that goes to the buzzer. Can anyone point at a sample circuit or application note on how to do this?

(*) Update: There is a (software) device driver which is not my own that turns the PWM signal on and off; when turning off, the PWM output stays at whatever level it was at that point.

Comment: Not sure why you can't control the PWM, but wouldn't a capacitor block DC? What frequency are you driving it at?

Comment: How are you generating the PWM? What are the software constraints exactly?

Comment: @RogerRowland Why: There is a (software) device driver which is not my own that turns the PWM signal on and off; when turning off, the PWM output stays at whatever level it was at that point. Freq: Typically 100Hz-1kHz. Capacitor: Yes I guess that could do the trick. Any sample circuit or app note?

Comment: Is there no way for you to edit the software at all?

Comment: Do you have a part number of the piezo buzzer?

Comment: Also when you generate these beeps, are they at constant intervals? What controls this interval? Have you checked what the PWM signal looks like with an oscilloscope?

Comment: @Hayman I think the question is generic and can be applicable to any piezo buzzer. Does the part number make any difference? Re. PWM signals: These are fine. I don't have any problem with the beeps themselves. The issue I am talking about is when I am _not_ generating beeps and the control signal goes idle.

Comment: The part number makes all the difference, I didn't ask for the sake of it. As for the PWM signals are you using PWM to generate an AC signal or are you just using pulsed on/off DC. My questions were to help me better answer your question. If you use a capacitor to block the DC component of the signal and you *are* using pulsed DC on/off to control your beeps then goodbye buzzer because you won't hear anything anymore. I'm trying to determine how you're driving the buzzer as the answer changes depending

Comment: I am using a PWM signal, hence what you call "pulsed on/off DC". By definition, "pulsed DC" is not just DC anymore since the resulting signal has frequency components >0. Whether I can hear the buzzer or not if I use a blocking capacitor will depend on the capacitor I use.

Comment: Put a capacitor in, if it works then great for you. If it doesn't work then come back. You never really fully answered any of my questions and replied with a *I know what I'm doing* answer without understanding why I was asking my question. If your beeps are periodic short duration beeps at wide intervals then I don't think using a capacitor is going to work.

Comment: I appreciate your intention to help and I did try to answer most of your questions. But questions like "Is there no way for you to edit the software at all" are not helping. Even if a software solution was possible, I am not looking for a sofware solution here, nor I am looking for anything specifically related to this specific buzzer. Nor I am looking for advise on how to generate a PWM signal. I am asking a general question on how to block the DC component when the PWM signal is idle.

Comment: I was trying to determine what the PWM signal looked like. [Here's a little simulation for you](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+4.252108200006279+50+5+43%0AR+208+272+112+272+1+2+100+2.5+0+0+0.5%0Ac+304+288+448+288+0+0.00009999999999999999+-45.1119228516842%0Ar+448+288+448+400+0+2%0Ag+448+400+448+464+0%0AS+304+288+208+288+0+0+false+0%0AR+208+304+96+304+0+1+100+50+0+0+0.5%0Ao+2+64+0+550+74.82888383134222+23.945242826029513+0+-1%0A) try clicking the switch to go between 100Hz AC and 100Hz pulsed DC and see what happens. This is what I was trying to figure it out for

Comment: That is a very nice tool that I wasn't aware of, so thank you for that :-). Yes I see what happens. The simulation is a bit misleading though. The AC source is set to 50Vpp whereas the CLK source is set to 2.5V max. The result also depends on the C and R values of course. [Here is a similar simulation with different values](http://goo.gl/sLfsH9).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38122/discussion-between-grodriguez-and-hayman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capacitor blocks DC and passes AC broadly speaking. maybe try a 10 uF capacitor. At 100 Hz it will have an AC impedance of 159 ohms. At 1 kHz it will be 15.9 ohms. Here's how: -

[image]

Your piezo load is the resistor in the above.

Comment: Can we be sure that it's an AC signal controlling the buzzer? If it's still audible at a constant voltage level and is used to generate 'beeps' isn't it more likely to be one of the little DC buzzers you can get from RS or Farnell?

Comment: @Hayman the OP says he's driving it at various frequencies so it's fair to assume it can work on AC but, if it doesn't he'll see our little conversation and have his answer!

Answer (score -1):

This is a recommended circuit for eliminating the DC component and avoiding the piezo as a voltage transducer which will play havoc with sensitive circuits. Use a MOSFET not a transistor. 
[image: From a TDK datasheet for Piezo buzzers]

Comment: There is no DC blocking action or component in this circuit. Can you explain your thinking? In addition, you have posted a circuit showing a transistor and advised the OP to use a MOSFET.